Where do political labels come from, academics or the parties themselves?
Where do labels such as "right-wing", "left-wing", "conservative", "liberal", "socialist", "capitalist", etc., come from? Do organizations identify themselves as such? Or do academic institutions come up with such labels, and then the public adopts them and applies them as they see fit? My point is, does any party or organization identify itself as conservative, for example? It's not as if a party identifying as conservative somehow forces them to adopt only conservative policies. Are such labels just for ease of reference?

Each of the labels you mention is going to have a different source, history, and modern use, and they simply can't all be answered in a single question. You're more likely to find experts for a single label on either the History site or English Language site

Another common source of political labels come from political opponents.

In Britain, the Conservative Party has been in power for more than half of the last 100 years.  They have used the name since the 1830s (having previously been the Tories).

Since the late 19th century, Denmark and Norway have had parties called Venstre,  literally "Left" but in fact traditionally liberal in a pro-democracy, anti-aristocracy and pro-capitalism sense, and so centre-right in the current political spectrum.

"Left/Right" mostly sitting order and opposing views. "Cons., lib, soc. cap". Well these are derived from actual words that have intrinsic meaning and either proponents or observers thought they fit for those groups or that stuck with them as names despite the programs having moved on.

Both.
Parties pick a name to identify themselves to potential voters. This ought to have some relation to what they do, or voters get confused, but they also get to define their own brand name with their messaging.
Consider, for instance, the different definitions of "socialist" in Europe and the US. In the US, calls for universal healthcare are portrayed as socialist. In Europe, even conservative parties are taking it for granted. Meanwhile, in the US, there is widespread agreement that sane and law-abiding citizens (at least) may own firearms, while in Europe even conservatives restrict this to citizens with a plausible need.

It would be nice if this answer could add some examples for both. Also one question would then be who come up first with each label. But this is more a history question.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, in Germany the party "Die Linke" has picked that name and it is pretty left-wing. The party "Christlich-Soziale Union" is quite catholic but probably not very social -- but their view would differ.


My point is, does any party or organization identify itself as conservative, for example?

This is actually very common. Several countries have major parties literally calling themselves: "The Left", "The Liberal Party", "The Social Democratic Party", "The Conservative Party" or "The Nationalist Party". I couldn't find any examples of non-fringe parties literally named "Capitalist Party". Probably due to the term "capitalist" generally having a negative connotation.
Looking at the histories of the formation of these parties, then it seems like they usually adopted their names from a political concept that was present in the political discourse of the time, but (in the eyes of the party founders) not adequately represented by any existing party.

"Probably due to the term "capitalist" generally having a negative connotation." I don't think it does, except among socialists et al. More likely, it doesn't appear in party names because in capitalist countries it's the default expectation and not worth marking (it adds no descriptive value to the name of a party) and in communist countries those parties' existence would not be tolerated.
